# Ignored attempt to cancel a touchstart event with cancelable=false while Drag-Drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, touch

Hi I am trying to drag some buttons/images in another div but I am getting following warning continuously.

```
Ignored attempt to cancel a touchstart event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.
```

Here is my code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>


<link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>



<script>

    $(function () {
        $(".btn-popup-sources img").draggable({
        cancel :false,
        revert: "invalid",
        refreshPositions: true,
        drag: function (event, ui) {
            ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
            var image = this.src.split("/")[this.src.split("/").length - 1];
            if ($.ui.ddmanager.drop(ui.helper.data("ui-draggable"), event)) {
                alert(image + " dropped.");
            }
            else {
                alert(image + " not dropped.");
            }
        }
    });
    $("#droppedHere").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            if ($("#droppedHere img").length == 0) {
                $("#droppedHere").html("");
            }
            ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
            $("#droppedHere").append(ui.draggable);
        }
    });

});

</script>
```

I tried to check but not find suitable solution on net.